# How can I add two hours to a timestamp value then reconvert it to a string with only the hours and minutes?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update a change I have made recently to a value in a table where I take the show time of a particular movie (which is stored as a string), then add two hours to it, and then store this new value in the show time column of a different movie (i.e. if the show time of Iron Man 2 is 18:45, I want to set the show time of Iron Man 3 as 20:45).

I first set the show time by carrying out the following query:

```
UPDATE movies 
SET show_time= 
    (TO_TIMESTAMP((SELECT show_time 
    FROM movies 
    WHERE title= 'Iron Man 2'), 'HH24:MI') + (2||'HOURS')::interval)
WHERE title='Iron Man 3'
```

This query gets the show time value of Iron Man 2, converts it from a string into a timestamp, and then adds two hours to it. Which ostensibly worked, until I looked at the value stored for show time for Iron Man 3:

```
id  title       year    show_time
3   Iron Man 2  2010    18:45
7   Iron Man 3  2013    0001-01-01 20:45:00-00:01:15 BC
```

I want to try and change the show time value so that it only has HH:MM format. I tried to do this with the following query:

```
   UPDATE movies
   SET show_time = 
       (TO_CHAR((SELECT show_time 
        FROM movies 
        WHERE title= 'Iron Man 3'), 'HH24:MI')
   WHERE title= 'Iron Man 3'
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

I have tried adjusting the code, but I cannot get it to work as a whole. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the time calculation, no need to convert it to a timestamp.

You can add an `interval` to a `time` value without the intermediate step, so you just need [to cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) your `show_time` column to a `time` value (assuming it's stored as `hh24:mi`)

```
UPDATE movies
    SET show_time = (select to_char(show_time::time + interval '2 hours', 'hh24:mi') 
                     from movies
                     where title = 'Iron Man 2')
WHERE title='Iron Man 3';
```

Another option would be a join:

```
update movies m1
  set show_time = to_char(m2.show_time::time + interval '2 hour', 'hh24:mi')
from movies m2
where m1.title = 'Iron Man 3'
  and m2.title = 'Iron Man 2';
```

Note that this approach will fail if the resulting runtime is wraps around at midnight.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f31dac761a2e4f4582acd655ba34bd7c)

---

As `show_time` stores a "time" value, you should change that column to the correct data type:

```
alter table movies
  alter column show_time type time using show_time::time;
```

Once you have done that, you don't need the casts (`show_time::time`)  any more.

Comment: Yep this worked out great, thanks so much. But I have one slight question: I'm not sure I understand what `::time` and `interval` stand for. In a previous comment you made, you mentioned that they were a data type, but are they a data type that one can "slice" from the `show_time` value (comparable to getting a value from a Python dict using a key)? Or does the `::` have a different function?

Comment: The `::` is the cast operator. `time` and `interval` are data types (like `integer`, `text` or `numeric`) So `show_time::time` converts the character value in that column a `time` value. `show_time::time` is the same as `cast(show_time as time)`. You don't have to do that if you create the column with the data type `time` right from the start

Comment: sadly I did not get to decide what datatype to make the column in the table. I had to work with what I was given. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the column show_time is VARCHAR, you need to convert it to TIMESTAMP and after convert to Formated VARCHAR again. Something like:

```
UPDATE movies SET show_time = TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(show_time, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM'), 'HH24:MI') WHERE title= 'Iron Man 3'
```

But, in your case, the error is because is missing the symbol ")"

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I have tried your approach and I have also added an end parenthesis to my own code and I still am unable to convert `0001-01-01 20:45:00-00:01:15 BC` to just `20:45`. I keep getting the error `ERROR:  invalid value "01-01" for "MON"
DETAIL:  The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this field.` when running your code.